# MySql behaves badly

Tags: php, mysql, database

Look at this code please, i'm using mysql.

```
create table `dictionary_one` (`dict_id` int(10) primary key)
engine = innodb;

create table `already_exists`(
  `pk_id`             int(10) primary key,
  `ref_dict_one_id`   int(10),
  constraint `Already_exists_ibfk_1` foreign key(`ref_dict_one_id`) references `dictionary_one`(`dict_id`)
);
```

It seems everything is going well so far. Now - add another column that references another table.

```
create table `dictionary_two` (`dict_id` int(10) primary key)
engine = innodb;

alter table `already_exists` add column `ref_dict_two_id` int(10), add foreign key `Already_exists_ibfk_2`(`ref_dict_two_id`) references `dictionary_two`(`dict_id`);
```

No syntax errors, everything is done right, but:

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table './test/already_exists' already exists
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and my question is... why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alter table `already_exists` 
  add column `ref_dict_two_id` int(10),

  add constraint `Already_exists_ibfk_2`
    foreign key (`ref_dict_two_id`) 
    references `dictionary_two`(`dict_id`);
```